# how to change value of input in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new in ionic and I need some help.

I have a page that has a form, and I'm receiving a parameter from another page to be injected into the form.

Now I was able to change the value of the input, but when I submit the form the value always comes undefined.

ts code

```
export class QpayPage {
  private qpay_form: FormGroup;
  id;
  merchant_id;
  constructor(public navParams: NavParams, private iab: InAppBrowser, public nav: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, public fetchphpProvider: FetchphpProvider) {

  this.id = this.navParams.get('id');
  this.qpay_form = this.formBuilder.group({
    merchant_id: [this.id, Validators.required],
    amount: ['', Validators.required],
    note: [''],
  });
 }
}
```

Html code

```
<form #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="qpay_form" (ngSubmit)="submitQpay(form)">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Merchant ID</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" required name="merchant_id"  [(ngModel)]="qpay_form.merchant_id" ngControl="merchant_id" formControlName="merchant_id"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Amount</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" required name="amount" [(ngModel)]="qpay_form.amount" ngControl="amount" formControlName="amount"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Note</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea name="note" [(ngModel)]="qpay_form.note" ngControl="note" formControlName="note"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" type="submit" block>Pay Now</button>
  </form>
```

Now here as I mentioned the value is changed you can visibly see it but I hit submit the value comes undefined, when I delete one digit and rewrite it then it will be submitted fine, which made think that the value is not actually changed and I need to trigger the change somehow.

Any help or useful tips?

In case you need ionic info:

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0

System:

    Node : v8.11.1
    npm  : 6.0.1
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Without showing full .ts code it's hard to tell, but it seems that you are not passing the value. So, you need to change:

`(ngSubmit)="submitQpay(form)"`

to

`(ngSubmit)="submitQpay(qpay_form.value)"`

and then in .ts file

```
submitQpay(formValue) {
   // code to handle value
}
```

Comment: Although I did not try your answer, but I think it's not my problem here, since the other inputs I can receive correctly. and the merchant id I can receive correctly if it was written manually.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question. I removed the whole form group and replace it with a function that reads the values of the inputs.

Html code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Merchant ID</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" required   [(ngModel)]="merchant_id" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Amount</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" required  [(ngModel)]="amount" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Note</ion-label>
  <ion-textarea name="note" [(ngModel)]="note" ></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="submitQpay()" block>Pay Now</button>
```

ts code:

```
merchant_id: string;
  amount: number;
  note: string;
  id;

submitQpay() { 
    this.fetchphpProvider.fetchurl(Number(this.merchant_id), this.amount,this.note).then(data => {
      this.url = data;
      console.log(this.url.payment_url);
      this.iab.create(this.url.payment_url, '_self', {
        toolbar : "no",
        fullscreen : "yes"
      });
    });
  }
```